# TYPO3: Suspicious values for "type" parameter. Security issue?

Tags: security, typo3

In the log module of a TYPO3 website I can see errors where people try to call the website with suspicious/random values for the "type" parameter which end up in an error message, since the type was not defined/configured.

Examples:

```
https://www.example.com/path/?type=694
https://www.example.com/path2/?type=219
```

Error message:

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1294587217:
>   The page is not configured! [type=694][]. This means that there is no
>   TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=694 configured.

Does anyone knows if there is a security issue which I am not aware of? Do I need to do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general URLs like `https://www.example.com/path/?type=694` can be regarded as save if the requested parameter-value for `type` is not configured with `config.typeNum` in TYPO3.

For most parameters there is an option to configure the allowed values in TYPO3, however it's explicitly not advised concerning `config.typeNum`, the reference for `TypoScript` states:

> Do not include the type parameter in the `config.linkVars` list, as this can result in unexpected behavior.

**Other parameters (NOT `type`! ) used with random values**

So, assumed there is another parameter which is requested with values that are not configured in the TYPO3 installation. A common parameter is `L` which is used for the language of the requested page. If there is a page with 3 languages then the main-language has the parameter `L=0`, the 2nd language the parameter `L=1` and the last language the parameter `L=2`.
In this case the allowed values can be configured in TypoScript with

```
config.linkVars = L(0-2)
```

If the allowed linkvars never represent a linear range, it can be configured like this:

```
config.linkVars = L(0|5|23)
```

A more general approach is possible too, so the values can be restricted at least representing integer-values:

```
config.linkVars = L(int)
```

**References:**

- [Configuration concerning `config.linkvars`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#linkvars)
- [Configuration concerning languages](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/TyposcriptConfiguration/Index.html)

**Additional considerations**

It is possible to filter not allowed page calls on a higher level, in the server-configuration (i.e. in a file `.htaccess`). Approach of this configuration could be included in the list

- not-allowed parameters (or values) are redirecting the user to the main-page or an error-page of TYPO3
- not-allowed parameters (or values) are redirecting the user to a page outside TYPO3, perhaps a static page without dynamic content
- not-allowed parameters (or values) are blocking the user from any server-access (usually for a define-able time of i.e. 10 minutes)
- page-requests with not-allowed parameters (or values) are logged or just dropped

This list is probably not complete but enough still to make some consideration.
There exist several opinions about those efforts, one opinion is that the system TYPO3 respectively the admin(s) should be informed about any access and are able perhaps to resolve some issues where users see an error but should see a regular page.
There might be still more arguments why TYPO3-admins should be informed about some not-provided parameters or parameter-values, but there are a few arguments which should be considered:

- DDOS attacks flood servers with requests till the server is unable to serve any request.
- In TYPO3 every request is filling some space in database and harddisk.
- firewalls also filter requests and no TYPO3-admin should be allowed probably to switch the firewall inactive, TYPO3 is without special steps not informed about requests the firewall blocks.

So, there might be some false parameters sent in good purpose, but many requests could have another purpose and it could be advisable to block or redirect some request-types. The server should be protected and the error-log by TYPO3 kept so far slim that logged errors are widely related to TYPO3-issues that could need interference of a TYPO3 admin.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation!